# Unordered function arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, arguments

Below is a regular function with named parameters:

```
function who(name, age, isMale, weight)
{
    alert(name + ' (' + (isMale ? 'male' : 'female') + '), ' + age + ' years old, ' + weight + ' kg.');
}

who('Jack', 30, true, 90); //this is OK.
```

What I want to achive is; whether you pass the arguments in order or not; the function should produce a similar result (if not the same):

```
who('Jack', 30, true, 90); //should produce the same result with the regular function
who(30, 90, true, 'Jack'); //should produce the same result
who(true, 30, 'Jack', 90); //should produce the same result
```

This enables you to pass a list of arguments in **any order** but still will be mapped to a logical order. My approach up to now is something like this:

```
function who()
{
    var name = getStringInArgs(arguments, 0); //gets first string in arguments
    var isMale = getBooleanInArgs(arguments, 0); //gets first boolean in arguments
    var age = getNumberInArgs(arguments, 0); //gets first number in arguments
    var weight = getNumberInArgs(arguments, 1); //gets second number in arguments

    alert(name + ' (' + (isMale ? 'male' : 'female') + '), ' + age + ' years old, ' + weight + ' kg.');
}
```

There is a little problem here; functions such as `getStringInArgs()` and `getNumberInArgs()` go through all the arguments each time to find the arg by type at the specified position. I could iterate through args only once and keep flags for the positions but then I would have to do it inside the who() function.

Do you think this approach is logical and the only way? Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT 1:** Code above actually works. I just want to know if there is a better way.

**EDIT 2**: You may wonder if this is necessary or whether it makes sense. The main reason is: I'm writing a jQuery function which adds a specific style to a DOM element. I want this function to treat its arguments like shorthand CSS values.

Example:

```
border: 1px solid red;
border: solid 1px red; /*will produce the same*/
```

So; here is the real and final code upto now:

```
(function($){
function getArgument(args, type, occurrence, defaultValue)
{
    if (args.length == 0) return defaultValue;

    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
          if (typeof args[i] === type)
          {
              if (count == occurrence) { return args[i]; }
              else { count++; }
          }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}

$.fn.shadow = function()
{
    var blur = getArgument(arguments, 'number', 0, 3);
    var hLength = getArgument(arguments, 'number', 1, 0);
    var vLength = getArgument(arguments, 'number', 2, 0);
    var color = getArgument(arguments, 'string', 0, '#000');
    var inset = getArgument(arguments, 'boolean', 0, false);
    var strInset = inset ? 'inset ' : '';

    var sValue = strInset + hLength + 'px ' + vLength + 'px ' + blur + 'px ' + color;
    var style = {
        '-moz-box-shadow': sValue,
        '-webkit-box-shadow': sValue,
        'box-shadow': sValue
    };

    return this.each(function()
    {
        $(this).css(style);
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage**:

```
$('.dropShadow').shadow(true, 3, 3, 5, '#FF0000');
$('.dropShadow').shadow(3, 3, 5, '#FF0000', true);
$('.dropShadow').shadow();
```

Comment: I think while you have two Number type argument you couldn't do that. It's possible if every argument had different type

Comment: @Mohsen, this actually works. There is no problem with multiple number-type arguments. Same type arguments are ordered in fact. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 7):

I find using objects to be more straight-forward and less error prone in the future:

```
var person = {
 name: 'Jack',
 age: 30,
 isMale: true,
 weight: 90
};

who(person);

function who(person){
 alert(person.name + 
  ' (' + (person.isMale ? 'male' : 'female') + '), ' + 
  person.age + ' years old, ' +
  person.weight + ' kg.');
}
```

That way when you come back years later you don't have to lookup to see if age was the first, second, or fifth number and is more descriptive of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are completely right but that's not what I'm looking for. I know I 'll have to document these kind of functions clearly but that's ok. thanks anyway.

Comment: @radgar, go with this method, you can do what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This seems unnecessarily complex, not just from the perspective of the function, which needs to reorder its arguments, but also from the perspective of whoever is calling.  You say that the function can accept its paramters in **any order**, but that's not entirely true.  Since your determination of which variable is which is based on type, it relies on each variable being a different type.  The name and gender can be anywhere, but the numeric arguments have to be in a specific order.  It also prevents someone from passing in "30" or "90", which are numbers but will be regarded as strings - confusing it with the name and not finding an age or weight.

Comment: In fact; that's why I made 'any order' bold : ) I should depict again that; the arguments are in fact mapped into a logical order.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and that your existing code works, I'm just not sure why.  Could you provide a use case in which this is desirable behavior?

Comment: I've added the actual code to the post and the reason I need it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the arguments of a specific type in the arguments array. This is a **big hack**, you could follow the same pattern with the other getTypeInArgs

```
function getNumberInArgs(args, index) {
    if (!args.numbers) {    
      args.numbers = [];
      for (var i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
        // You have to implement isNumber
        if ( isNumber (args[i]) ) {
          args.numbers.push(args[i];
        }      
      }
    }
    return args.numbers[index];
}
```

I've never heard of accepting arguments in any order, except for the implode function in PHP, and it's marked on its [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) page as a big hack for historical reasons. So I wouldn't do this. If the order is too confusing, I would use the approach of taking a literal object, as suggested by WSkid.

Comment: With the edit, I can understand why you'd want to do it that way. However, the code I suggested is still addressing the problem you mentioned. You don't want getNumberInArgs to scan over all the arguments every time and you don't want to cache the results from the calling function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the re-scan problem remains but as @missingno said; maybe it's not an issue unless the function can receive hundreds of arguments. Maybe I should limit the for loop to expected number of arguments.

Comment: By the way, your way to test for numbers, strings and booleans will fail if any of arguments were created with `new Boolean, new String or new Number`

Comment: +1 :) Thanks for the heads-up. Seems the `typeof` operator is buggy. Fixed it via http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/

Answer (score 1):

You could try copying the arguments array into something you can destructively update:

<s>*untested code:*</s> Edit: I think it works now.

```
function args_getter(their_arguments){
    //copy arguments object into an actual array
    //so we can use array methods on it:
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(their_arguments);

    return function(type){
        var arg;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            arg = arr[i];
            if(type == typeof arg){
                arr.slice(i, 1);
                return arg;
            }
        }
        return "do some error handling here"
    }
}

function foo(){
    var args = args_getter(arguments);
    var b1 = args('boolean');
    var b2 = args('boolean');
    var n1 = args('number');
    console.log(n1, b1, b2);
}

//all of
// foo(1, true, false),
// foo(true, 1, false), and
// foo(true, false, 1)
// should print (1, true, false)
```

This is still O(N^2) since you go through the array every time. However this shouldn't be an issue unless your functions can receive hundreds of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Griffin.  This cannot be done unless you limit the choices more than you have.  As it is, you have a string, a boolean and two numbers.  Without some more rules on what can be in what position, you cannot tell which number is which.  If you're willing to make some rule about which number comes first or which number comes after some other argument, then you can sort it out.  In general, I think this is a bad idea.  It's much better (from the standpoint of good programming) to use an object like WSkid suggested.

Anyway, if you wanted to make a rule like the weight has to come after the age, then it could be done like this:

```
function findParm(args, type) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (typeof args[i] == type) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(-1);
}

function who(name, age, isMale, weight) {
    // assumes all variables have been passed with the right type
    // age is before weight, but others can be in any order

    var _name, _age, _isMale, _weight, i;

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    _name = args[findParm(args, "string")];     // only string parameter
    _isMale = args[findParm(args, "boolean")];  // only boolean parameter
    i = findParm(args, "number");               // first number parameter
    _age = args[i];
    args.splice(i, 1);                          // get rid of first number
    _weight = args[findParm(args, "number")];   // second number parameter

    // you now have the properly ordered parameters in the four local variables
    // _name, _age, _isMale, _weight
}

who("fred", 50, false, 100);
```

Working here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GP9cW/.

What I would suggest is better programming is something like this:

```
function who(items) {
    console.log(items.name);
    console.log(items.age);
    console.log(items.weight);
    console.log(items.isMale);
}

who({name: "Ted", age: 52, weight: 100, isMale: true});
```

Comment: arguments is not an actual array and doesn't have a spice method (at least on my browser...)

Comment: Just do `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)` and args is a regular array with the same contents as arguments and you can call all the array methods on it.

Comment: @Juan Mendes - I did do that and fixed a few other booboos in the code.  It works now in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
function who({name, age, isMale, weight}) 
{
    alert(name + ' (' + (isMale ? 'male' : 'female') + '), ' + age + ' years old, ' + weight + ' kg.'); 
}

who({name:'Jack', age:30, isMale:true, weight90});
```

Taking parameters as an object, allows you to pass arguments in any order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this since you have arguments of the same type.

Unless age and weight have *non-overlapping* ranges, you can't do this. How are you supposed to distinguish between 30 and 60 for weight or age??

Comment: I already distinguish them by type and position (order). Maybe I shouldn't say 'unordered' in the topic but it kind of explains what I need. thanks.

Comment: If you are going to stipulate that ages comes before weight, why would you not just have the parameters ordered (like a normal function?). It  makes no sense.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense since `1px red solid` can be in *any* order. Again you are stating that only **some** parameters need to be in order, why not make them all in order, you are actually complicating the problem of passing arguments. Also, in languages where you can set blur or drop shadow (see actionscript 3) the parameters need to give given in a certain order - it's for a reason!

Comment: He's trying to resemble the CSS parameters that don't need to be ordered.

Comment: I see your point and maybe you are right. AS3 has filter packages which are separate classes with ordered/named parameters. But here, I'm actually adding CSS to an element so I'm following the pattern of CSS shorthand values. Then again maybe not so necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
function who(items) {    console.log(items.name);    console.log(items.age);    console.log(items.weight);    console.log(items.isMale);}who({name: "Ted", age: 52, weight: 100, isMale: true});
```

That a previous posted sent seems sensible. But why make things complicated. My experience when people make things complicated things go wrong.

BTW - The solution above (as the previous posted gave) is similar to the Perl solution.